Cloning an installation to more than one machine
Can I clone an existing Ubuntu 24.04.1 installation to more than one machine and still have Ubuntu Pro and the software update system recognize the two machines as different?  After I install the cloned image on each machine, I want to be able to have a different set of apps on each machine.
Also can you recommend a cloning app for this purpose?

You'll need to generate individual machine IDs and then enroll Ubuntu Pro separately on each system.  Otherwise there's no way for it to ID different machines.  You also have to define different hostnames, etc. in the process for it to not be confusing.

I would vote for Clonezilla as your cloning app. Although it may not be the most user friendly or slick, it's a great tool and one I rely on constantly. https://clonezilla.org/
